# How to code how many prime numbers are there between 1 million and 2 million on MATLAB

Tags: prime-numbers, matlab

How would I find the total number of prime numbers between 1 million and 2 million on MATLAB. I have the code for displaying every prime number between 2 integers being:

```
n = firstnumber : secondnumber;
p = isprime(n);
n(p)     %displays the primes
```

But how would I code it so it gives me a total number of primes between 2 numbers.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: From `p`,  you only need `sum(p)` or `nnz(p)`

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily the most efficient way of doing it but for your numbers it's still very fast:

```
p = primes(secondnumber);
n = length(find(p>=firstnumber));
```

About 20ms here.

Answer (score 0):

With Mathematica

```
Select[Range[10^6, 2*10^6], PrimeQ] // Length // Timing
{0.515625, 70435}
```

I suspect an equally fast test existing in matlab, using the function isprime() mapped into an array.